# Height animation does not work

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qt5

I'm trying to create `TableView` with rows that can expand and show some content on click. It works, but does not show height property animation. I tried to add `ColorAnimation` and change expanded row color to black and it works well, but for some reason it does not work for height.
Here is the code of my table view:

```
TableView {
        id: myTableView
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 12
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 12
        anchors.rightMargin: 10

        model: myModel

        ListModel {
          //...
        }

        rowDelegate: Item {
            id: myRowDelegate

            Rectangle {
                id: rect
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.right: parent.right
                color: styleData.alternate ? "#d9e5ea" : "white"

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        myRowDelegate.state = (myRowDelegate.state == "COLLAPSED") ? "EXPANDED" : "COLLAPSED";
                        console.log("click");
                    }
                }
            }
            state: "COLLAPSED"
            states: [
                State {
                    name: "COLLAPSED"
                    PropertyChanges { target: myRowDelegate; height: 22; }
                },
                State {
                    name: "EXPANDED"
                    PropertyChanges { target: myRowDelegate; height: 400; }
                   // PropertyChanges { target: rect; color: "black"; }
                }
            ]
            transitions: [
                Transition {
                    from: "EXPANDED"
                    to: "COLLAPSED"
                    PropertyAnimation { property: height; duration: 400; }
                  //  ColorAnimation { duration: 400; }
                },
                Transition {
                    from: "COLLAPSED"
                    to: "EXPANDED"
                    PropertyAnimation { property: height; duration: 400; }
                    //ColorAnimation { duration: 400; }
                }
            ]
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use property name as a string to make it work:

`PropertyAnimation { property:`**"height"**`; duration: 400; }`

You could also achieve that via `Behavior` (remove transitions for that):

```
Behavior on height {
   NumberAnimation { duration: 400 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I added `"height"` and it works as expected now. You saved me a lot of time, thanks.

Comment: @d''''''''''''''''''''''''''''', could you please clarify, why you unaccepted the answer after it saved you a lot of time?